# How to correctly set the lock in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, locks

There are two tables: `site (id, name, url)`, `page (id, code, content, path, site_id)`.  The site table has a record with id = 1. The page table is empty.

I'm trying to insert a new record into the Page table if it doesn't already exist, using transactions (concurrently). For this purpose, I use a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` query to lock during validation so that I don't get two identical records in the table.

Isolation level for all transactions is **REPEATABLE_READ**. The transactions start as follows :

TRX 1:

```
START TRANSACTION;
select * from `page` where path = 'path' and site_id = 1 limit 1 for update;
```

TRX 2:

```
START TRANSACTION;
select * from `page` where path = 'path' and site_id = 1 limit 1 for update;
```

These queries use `LOCK_TYPE = Record`, `LOCK_MODE = X` locking. [This article](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/innodb-data-locking-part-2-locks/#:%7E:text=similar%20to%20this%3A-,%E2%86%93requested%20%5C%20held%E2%86%92,-S%2CREC_NOT_GAP) has a matrix reflecting, if a request for access in mode A has to wait for a transaction accessing the resource in mode B to finish. In matrix in the intersection of a row (`LOCK_MODE = X`) with a column (`LOCK_MODE = X`) stated WAITING. According to this, the second transaction must wait for the first transaction to complete because it uses this lock (`LOCK_TYPE = RECORD, LOCK_MODE = X`). However, in reality two identical locks are taken at the same time:

| ENGINE | ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID | OBJECT_NAME | LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INNODB | 6180 | page | TABLE | IX | GRANTED | NULL |
| INNODB | 6180 | page | RECORD | X | GRANTED | supremum pseudo-record |
| INNODB | 6178 | page | TABLE | IX | GRANTED | NULL |
| INNODB | 6178 | page | RECORD | X | GRANTED | supremum pseudo-record |

Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: That article never mentions `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`

Comment: `IX` means "Intention to grab an eXclusive lock".  When one grabs, the other will be blocked.  (Or something like that)

Comment: @Barmar The articale has a matrix reflecting if a request for access in mode A has to wait for a transaction accessing the resource in mode B to finish. In the intersection of a row (LOCK_MODE = X) with a column (LOCK_MODE = X) stated WAITING.

Comment: Why are you doing a `select .. for update`? What trouble are you having inserting concurrently?

Comment: @danblack I'm trying to insert a new record into the Page table if it doesn't already exist, using transactions (concurrently). For this purpose, I use a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` query to lock during validation so that I don't get two identical records in the table.

Comment: Use a unique key to enforce a constraint and handle a duplicate key exception in your application.

Comment: @danblack That doesn't seem possible since I am not in charge of the table structure.